# dir + file.copy returns "file does not exist" warnings due to non-english characters, how can I fix this?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have this function in RStudio to synchronize 2 folders on windows.

***p1 and p2 are paths;***

```
  fsync<-function(p1,p2){
  A<-dir(p1,all.files = T,recursive = T,ignore.case = T, include.dirs = F,full.names = T);
  B<-dir(p2,all.files = T,recursive = T,ignore.case = T, include.dirs = F,full.names = T);
  d1<-setdiff(A,B);
  d2<-setdiff(B,A);
  if(length(d1)!=0) file.copy(d1,p2,overwrite = F,recursive = T)
  if(length(d2)!=0) file.copy(d2,p1,overwrite = F,recursive = T)
}
```

When I run it, it worked, but also shows warnings saying **"the file does not exist"** or **"no such file or directory"** (I'm not really sure right now). I think it is only with files containning non-english characters `(e.g. á, é, ...).` How can I make `dir()` take the file names correctly?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is actually a really good first question!

Comment: Try removing `full.names = T` from both `dir()` statements, I'm wondering if it's an issue that you're passing the additional path characters to `file.copy`

Comment: First time I wrote this, I didn't include full.names=T, and file.copy failed because d1 and d2 weren't valid paths, I think.